# Is it possible to style individual tab bars?

Tags: qt

I would like to style individual tabs of the tab bar of a QTabWidget (not hover or current but an individual one)  WHY? because I need to get the user's attention so that he knows urgent information appeared in that tab. There can be multiple tabs that need attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to assemble your own tab widget but i think if you subclass `QTabBar` and use  `setTabButton(int index, ...)` you can set a custom widget for the item in the tab, this would let you control the behaviour and you could change it through code or style it via the property selector e.g.

```
QTabBar MyButtonWidget[showalert=true] 
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little strange. Why don't you start with that tab selected?

I don't think you can do that with stylesheets. You can easily customize first and last but not any tab (AFAIK)

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/stylesheet-reference.html

On the other hand you can set custom icon to draw attention or use void QTabBar::setTabTextColor ( int index, const QColor & color )

Comment: the reason I am doing this is because each tab displays data for a piece of Hardware equipment.  if a fault occurs then its an emergency and they need to know where the fault is coming from and get to the corresponding tab.  That is why a selected tab is not sufficient.

Comment: As pointed out by Anton, you could color the tab. If it's an emergency than switching tabs may be warranted.  Other options include using a popup or having an alert widget that becomes visible when a fault occurs.

Comment: How about adding QLabel above tabs with message that something bad happen and link/button which navigates to the tab in question. When there is no error the message will be hidden.

Comment: that is one of my options but I dint want to go there.

Comment: @Kaleb: only the text color can be changed. That might not grab enough attention to it but it could do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try simply using stylesheets to directly style a tab instead of subclassing just for that purpose. In the stylesheet, you can use the :tab subcontrol to access a single tab, and you can then modify a dynamic propoerty to set its state as either needing attention or not, and applying the style based on the dynamic property.

See : [:tab sub control](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/stylesheet-reference.html#tab-sub)  ,  [Customizing using dynamic properties](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties)

Comment: no that would not work, i cannot select exactly which tab to style.  For example if I have 15 tabs i cant say :tab:3 only tab:left tab:right, tab:middle etc..

Comment: @yan: you could, however, use QTabBar::tab[urgent="true"], then in your code, set a dynamic property on the tab that needs attention with aTab->setProperty("urgent", true); when appropriate

Comment: would like to beleive you but I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Probably I am not doing right but I don't see a way of adding a dynamic property to an individual tab, only to the whole QTabWidget or QTabBar. If you could add more detail I will try it.

Comment: Upvoting the last comment. I would also like to know how to add a dynamic property to a specific tab in a QTabBar.